# Divide Time by two

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a easy solution for dividing a time? For example divide 04:00:30 by two and get 2:00:15?

```
select FIRMA, NR, CAST(Zeit AS TIME(0)) as Zeit 
  from [2_2017] 
where Art='D' 
and Zeit is not Null 
and Zeit !='00:00:00'and Tour_1 ='0' 
order by Firma,NR
```

Comment: Excusez moi, I searched but did not found this solution... And it's excatly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: No problem glad to help to point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you first need to convert time to some integer as sec, min , hours from midnight and then devide it and add back to midnight

```
   DECLARE @zeint time = '23:00:15'
declare @midnight  time ='00:00:00'
select 
    dateadd(SECOND,
                (DATEDIFF(SECOND,@midnight, @zeint)/2)
            ,@midnight) as half
```